# sqoop hive import with partitions

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, parquet, partition

I have some sqoop jobs importing into hive that I want to partition, but I can't get it to function. The import will actually work: the table is sqooped, it's visible in hive, there's data but the partition parameters I'm expecting to see don't appear when I describe the table. I HAVE sqooped this table as a csv, created an external parquet table, and inserted the data into that (which works), but I want to be able to avoid the extra steps if possible. here's my current code. Am I missing something or am I trying to do the impossible? thanks!

```
sqoop import -Doraoop.import.hint=" " \
--options-file /home/[user]/pass.txt \
--verbose \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://oid:389/cn=OracleContext,dc=[employer],dc=com/SQSOP051 \
--username [user]\
--num-mappers 10 \
--hive-import \
--query "select DISC_PROF_SK_ID, CLM_RT_DISC_IND, EASY_PAY_PLN_DISC_IND, TO_CHAR(L40_ATOMIC_TS,'YYYY') as YEAR, TO_CHAR(L40_ATOMIC_TS,'MM') as MONTH from ${DataSource[index]}.$TableName where \$CONDITIONS" \
--hive-database [dru_user] \
--hcatalog-partition-keys YEAR \
--hcatalog-partition-values '2015' \
--target-dir hdfs://nameservice1/data/res/warehouse/finance/[dru_user]/Claims_Data/$TableName \
--hive-table $TableName'testing' \
--split-by ${SplitBy[index]} \
--delete-target-dir \
--direct \
--null-string '\\N' \
--null-non-string '\\N' \
--as-parquetfile \
```

Comment: Partition key should be positioned last in the query

Comment: @leftjoin do you mean within the --query "______" part, or that I should be moving the --hcatalog options to underneath --as-parquetfile?

Comment: in the --query, yes.

Comment: @leftjoin that doesn't work when I try it.

Comment: It seems, that at the time --as-parquetfile option and sqoop import with partitioning doesn't work. Based on:
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Kite-SDK-includes-Morphlines/Importing-data-from-oracle-using-sqoop-into-a-partitioned-hive/td-p/46201

Comment: why do you have `options-file` with the options specified? I think you want to use a password file only!

Comment: @sumit Kumar Ghosh all that's in pass.txt is a password, should I have done something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the `options-file` by `--password-file`. However that will not solve the partition problem. For the partition problem  you can try creating the partition-ed table `$TableName` partitioned first before the import.

```
sqoop import -Doraoop.import.hint=" "               \
  --password-file /home/[user]/pass.txt             \
  --verbose                                         \
  --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://oid:389/cn=OracleContext,dc=[employer],dc=com/SQSOP051                              \
  --username [user]                                 \
  --num-mappers 10                                  \
  --hive-import                                     \
  --query "SELECT disc_prof_sk_id, 
       clm_rt_disc_ind, 
       easy_pay_pln_disc_ind, 
       To_char(l40_atomic_ts,'YYYY') AS year, 
       To_char(l40_atomic_ts,'MM')   AS month 
    FROM   ${DataSource[index]}.$tablename 
    WHERE  \$conditions"                            \
  --hcatalog-database [dru_user]                    \
  --hcatalog-partition-key     YEAR                 \
  --hcatalog-partition-values '2015'                \
  --target-dir hdfs://nameservice1/data/res/warehouse/finance/[dru_user]/Claims_Data/$TableName                                                   \
  --hcatalog-table $TableName                       \
  --split-by ${SplitBy[index]}                      \
  --delete-target-dir                               \
  --direct                                          \
  --null-string '\\N'                               \
  --null-non-string '\\N'                           \
  --as-parquetfile
```